# Microsoft Cognitive Entity Search API - only returns 4-6 results

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the Bing Entity Search API to search for dentists in a city and I only get 4-6 results.  There should be hundreds of results.

This is the sample from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-local-business-search/quickstarts/local-quickstart) which is for local business seach api but I changed uri to use entity search api.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace localSearch
{
    class Program
    {
    // **********************************************
    // *** Update or verify the following values. ***
    // **********************************************

    // Replace the accessKey string value with your valid access key.
    const string accessKey = "my key";


    const string uriBase = "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/entities/";

    const string searchTerm = "dentist florida";

    // Returns search results including relevant headers
    struct SearchResult
    {
        public String jsonResult;
        public Dictionary<String, String> relevantHeaders;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        Console.WriteLine("Searching locally for: " + searchTerm);

        SearchResult result = BingLocalSearch(searchTerm, accessKey);

        Console.WriteLine("\nRelevant HTTP Headers:\n");
        foreach (var header in result.relevantHeaders)
            Console.WriteLine(header.Key + ": " + header.Value);

        Console.WriteLine("\nJSON Response:\n");
        Console.WriteLine(JsonPrettyPrint(result.jsonResult));
       // File.WriteAllText("c:\temp\bingsearch1.json", Newtonsoft.Json. result.jsonResult);
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\temp\movie.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.jsonResult));
        Console.Write("\nPress Enter to exit ");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs a Bing Local business search and return the results as a SearchResult.
    /// </summary>
    static SearchResult BingLocalSearch(string searchQuery, string key)
    {
        // Construct the URI of the search request
        var uriQuery = uriBase + "?q=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(searchQuery) + "&mkt=en-us";

        // Perform the Web request and get the response
        WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(uriQuery);
        request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = key;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponseAsync().Result;
        string json = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        // Create result object for return
        var searchResult = new SearchResult();
        searchResult.jsonResult = json;
        searchResult.relevantHeaders = new Dictionary<String, String>();

        // Extract Bing HTTP headers
        foreach (String header in response.Headers)
        {
            if (header.StartsWith("BingAPIs-") || header.StartsWith("X-MSEdge-"))
                searchResult.relevantHeaders[header] = response.Headers[header];
        }

        return searchResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Formats the given JSON string by adding line breaks and indents.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json">The raw JSON string to format.</param>
    /// <returns>The formatted JSON string.</returns>
    static string JsonPrettyPrint(string json)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            return string.Empty;

        json = json.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "").Replace("\t", "");

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        bool quote = false;
        bool ignore = false;
        int offset = 0;
        int indentLength = 3;

        foreach (char ch in json)
        {
            switch (ch)
            {
                case '"':
                    if (!ignore) quote = !quote;
                    break;
                case '\'':
                    if (quote) ignore = !ignore;
                    break;
            }

            if (quote)
                sb.Append(ch);
            else
            {
                switch (ch)
                {
                    case '{':
                    case '[':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', ++offset * indentLength));
                        break;
                    case '}':
                    case ']':
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', --offset * indentLength));
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        break;
                    case ',':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                        sb.Append(new string(' ', offset * indentLength));
                        break;
                    case ':':
                        sb.Append(ch);
                        sb.Append(' ');
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (ch != ' ') sb.Append(ch);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        return sb.ToString().Trim();
    }
}
```

}

Is there a way to increase the search results returned?

Comment: What's wrong with the answer?

Comment: I saw you posted something then removed it before I had a chance to try it.

Comment: How do you create an api key for this ?